# Can JMeter support HTTP method CONNECT

Tags: http, jmeter, fiddler, jmeter-plugins, har

[HTTP method CONNECT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) is part of available HTTP methods,

In Fiddler HTTP CONNECT is also saved and can be export to HAR format and then converted to JMeter script,

In JMeter those [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) are failing,for example request `CONNECT http://graph.facebook.com:443/`

With the following error:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:839)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:697)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:455)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:212)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    ... 10 more
```

CONNECT isn't mention in HTTP Request component:

> GET, POST, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH (not supported for JAVA implementation). With HttpClient4, the following methods related to WebDav are also allowed: COPY, LOCK, MKCOL, MOVE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, UNLOCK, REPORT, MKCALENDAR, SEARCH.

Can CONNECT method be execute in JMeter? if not what can be the fix? change to other method or only remove those requests from script?

**EDIT**

I also failed in HTTP Raw Request to execute similar CONNECT method.errors: `Response message: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException` or `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

I also failed to change to GET or https protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin may help you:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/

Working example:

[image: Raw Connect Request]

Maybe open a bugzilla request or ask on user mailing list of other core options or enhancement request.